# Jekyll if statement not working

Tags: class, if-statement, jekyll

I have the following if statement in Jekyll:

```
  {%assign current = page.url | split: '/' %}
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="../product-type/index.html" 
   {% if current == "product-type" %} class="active-circle"{% endif %}>
  <div class="circle"></div>
   </a></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
Even if I go into the compiled HTML file and add the "active-circle" class manually, the CSS for that class does not show up in my browser, and the link doesn't have that class when I inspect the element!

This WAS working earlier (I just have some CSS that changes the background color of div class="circle"). After I changed my build destination to a specified folder, it stopped working. I've printed out what {{current}} is just to be sure, and it is indeed what I'm checking for. I've also tried adding just a test "if" statement elsewhere, and that doesn't work, either.

Is anything wrong with my if statement?! I've been staring at this for hours and have no idea what went wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

The `split` liquid filter always returns an array.

Try :

```
{% assign myArray = "/a/b/c/" | split: "/" %}
<p>{{ myArray }}</p>          ---> abc
<p>{{ myArray | inspect}}</p> ---> ["", "a", "b", "c"]
```

In your case, you have :

```
{% assign current = "/product-type/" | split:"/" %}
<p>{{current | inspect}}</p>      --> ["", "product-type"]
<p>{{current.last | inspect}}</p> --> "product-type"
```

Now you can compare with :

```
{% if current.last == "product-type" %}  --> true
```